# How to use an user control with iFrame in asp.net webforms

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iframe

I am working on a C# asp.net web forms project. It has a master page. I have an user control which reads data from database, creates an un-ordered list in html string and populates a placeholder with it. This user control has to be automatically refreshed every 2 minutes. I have included this usercontrol on the master page. I have the following code to refresh the user control. The problem is the entire master page refreshes. I think using iFrame which in turns holds the user control may refresh just the iFrame. I do't know how to use an iFrame with user controls. Are there any sample code using iFrame with user control Or are there any alternate better solution?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval('refreshPage()', 20000);
    });

    function refreshPage() { 
        location.reload(); 
    }
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sound like a job for a `UpdatePanel`. Then only the contents inside the panel gets refreshed.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="20000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>

        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And the OnTick method

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

For this to work you do need a ScriptManager on the Master or the Child page.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: Hi VDWWD, I have integrated this code. I even added <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
            </Triggers> Still the page flickers. Thanks